# How to guarantee sequence of execution of multiple sinks in spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

In my scenario, I have a structured streaming application which reads from kafka and writes to hdfs and kafka using 3 different sinks. Primary sink is the hdfs one and others are secondary. I want the primary sink to run first and then secondary sinks. All have a triggertime of 60seconds. Is there a way to achieve that in spark structured streaming. Adding the code snippet:

```
val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .master(StreamerConfig.sparkMaster)
      .appName(StreamerConfig.sparkAppName)
      .getOrCreate()

    spark.conf.set("spark.sql.orc.impl", "native")
  spark.conf.set("spark.streaming.stopGracefullyOnShutdown","true")
    spark.conf.set("spark.sql.files.ignoreCorruptFiles","true")
    spark.conf.set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled","true")
    spark.conf.set("spark.shuffle.service.enabled","true")

val readData = spark
    .readStream
    .format("kafka")   .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers",StreamerConfig.kafkaBootstrapServer)
    .option("subscribe",StreamerConfig.topicName)
    .option("failOnDataLoss", false)
    .option("startingOffsets",StreamerConfig.kafkaStartingOffset)  .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger",StreamerConfig.maxOffsetsPerTrigger)
    .load()

  val deserializedRecords = StreamerUtils.deserializeAndMapData(readData,spark)

  
  val streamingQuery = deserializedRecords.writeStream
    .queryName(s"Persist data to hive table for ${StreamerConfig.topicName}")
    .outputMode("append")
    .format("orc")
    .option("path",StreamerConfig.hdfsLandingPath)
    .option("checkpointLocation",StreamerConfig.checkpointLocation)
    .partitionBy("date","hour")
    .option("truncate","false")
    .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(StreamerConfig.triggerTime))
    .start()

    
    deserializedRecords.select(to_json(struct("*")).alias("value"))
      .writeStream
      .format("kafka") // Local Testing - "console"
      .option("topic", StreamerConfig.watermarkKafkaTopic)
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", StreamerConfig.kafkaBroker)
      .option("checkpointLocation", StreamerConfig.phase1Checkpoints)
      .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(StreamerConfig.triggerTime))
      .start()
  

  
    deserializedRecords.select(to_json(struct("*")).alias("value"))
      .writeStream
      .format("kafka") // Local Testing - "console"
      .option("topic", StreamerConfig.watermarkKafkaTopic)
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", StreamerConfig.kafkaBroker)
      .option("checkpointLocation", StreamerConfig.phase2Checkpoints)
      .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(StreamerConfig.triggerTime))
      .start()
```

PS: I am using spark 2.3.2

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet of what you are trying to do and also the behavior currently?

Comment: Added the sample code snippet..

Comment: From the above code it should not matter which query gets executed first  since what is written to hdfs and kafka does not depend on the order of execution so is there a reason why you need that way?

Comment: Yes. We have written a KafkaLagListener which keeps a track in the current lag and posts that value as metric and we have alerts created on top of that in grafana.. As, there are 3 sinks, lag posting is happening wrong since kafka sinks are faster than hdfs and we want see the lag for hdfs sinks.

Comment: Order would  really depend on how fast these sinks are and not just dependent on  spark. As  Hdfs is a file write which could be slower in general. I would suggest having an alert mechanism using a cron job sort of scheduler which regularly checks the hdfs directory and alerts when there is a new write.

Comment: Yes. But, how to observe the lag since all the sinks have same consumer group and specifically, we want the lag to be reported only for hdfs sink, not the other kafka sinks. How can we isolate these sinks and make the listener to report lag for only HDFS sink. That's what we want to achieve.